# dot plot dynamcially control ylim

Tags: r

I would like to do a dot plot and show the count on the y axis instead of the denisty AND have the ylim() adjust dynamcially

```
library(ggplot2)
d = data.frame( x = c(-.5,-.06,-.051,-.049,-.03,.02), color = c("red", "red", "red","green", "red","blue"))
set.seed(1)
#d= data.frame(x = rnorm(10))
binwidth= .025
p=ggplot(d, aes(x = x)) + geom_dotplot(binwidth = binwidth, method="histodot") +  coord_fixed(ratio=binwidth) 
p +  ylim(0, ceiling(max(table(cut(p$data$x, (diff(range(p$data$x))/binwidth)))))*1.2)
```

Is there a way to apply the coloring that is in the "color" column of the dataframe?

Also the size of the plot changes when you change the binwidth variable.  Change the binwidth variable to .1 and you will see the plot becomes larger. Is there a way to have the plot be the same size?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

We can determine this number with

```
p = ggplot(d, aes(x = x)) + geom_dotplot(binwidth = .05, method="histodot") + coord_fixed(ratio=0.05)

p + ylim(0, ceiling(max(table(cut(p$data$x, (diff(range(p$data$x))/0.05)))))*1.2)
```

Find range of the values

`diff(range(p$data$x))`

Divide by the binwidth or coord_fixed ratio to find number of cuts

`diff(range(p$data$x))/p$coordinates$ratio`

Assign each number to a bin based on the number of cuts determined above

`cut(p$data$x, diff(range(p$data$x))/p$coordinates$ratio)`

Find the bin with the maximum number of observations. This number might not exactly match up with the plot, but that should not be an issue.

`ceiling(max(table(cut(p$data$x, (diff(range(p$data$x))/0.05)))))*1.2`

Comment: Thanks @Vlo but what is p$data$x. Can you apply this to my example where I call ylim(0,100)?

Comment: @user3022875 Oh, `p = ggplot(your plot)` saved to a variable without the `ylim` part. You can apply multiply by a scaler at the last step for some tuning. This works most of the time based on my tests.

Comment: if p = ggplot then won't the plot be incorrect. Are you saying to plot it twice? once to get the p and another time to calculate this ceiling from p and then have another ggplot with the correct scaling?

Comment: @user3022875 See edit. Save p as a plot. Read the parameters you specific during plotting to dynamically append a ylim.

Comment: can you run my edited code I am getting error Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class numeric

Comment: @user3022875 Change d back to a data.frame `d = data.frame(x = rnorm(300))`

Comment: Sorry about that.  Do you know if there is a way to apply color groupings? If I wanted to color the first point red  is that possible?

Comment: What is `first`? The top most member of each bin? The far left group?

Comment: I have added a color vector. See edits. Is it possible to apply the coloring in that vector to the points. And also the size of the chart is changing when the binwidth variable changes. Is there a way to fix the plot size?  Thank you again.

Comment: @user3022875 `geom_dotplot(binwidth = binwidth, method="histodot", aes(fill = color))` and `+ scale_fill_manual(values = c("#000099", "#009933", "#FF0000"))` The green dot is hiding behind the red. You need to change the scaling parameter from 1.2 to something higher since you only have 5 data points.

Comment: Thank you I will change the scaling. Are you saying the green dot is hiding because of the scaling? Is that why it is hiding or is there another way to make it stack on top of one another?

Comment: @user3022875 I don't know, but if you remove `method="histodot"`, part of the green dot can be seen. Only noticed this since the plot produces 5 dots with 6 data points. If you are trying to plot a few points, you are better off just assigning x, y coordinates to these points and using geom_point. You'll get have access to more robust controls of everything.

Comment: Ok do you know if anything can be done about the resulting size of the plot. As you change the binwidth it changes in size I think due to using coord_fixed and sometimes depending on the binwidth you select the plot is almost unreadable.